# Android/iOS: How to create a web-app, using native componentes?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, native, iphone-web-app

I've a responsive designed web-project. Everything works fine on mobile devices, but I'd like to create apps (Android/iOS) to use the native components like:

- Camera
- GPS
- local storage
- Calendar
- push/pull

Is there any way to combine the web-app with native components without re-writing the entire existing project?

**Idea**:

- create a native app
- use the native browser-component
- store the contents (HTML/CSS/Images/API-data) local
- show the local contents, if there's no connection
- store the made changes local (json)
- use native componentes *(e.g.: make a photo, save it to a temp-folder, upload via browser onSync())*
- sync when internet-connection available

I've not that much experience in app-development and would like to know the best-practices. Maybe there's a common framework that solves this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!

B.

Comment: Have a look at: http://cordova.apache.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a cross-platform app using framework like [phoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) for example.

With his java script methods you can use the device native components.

This is a [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/) for that.

Hope that helps